# Application Key and AccessToken are not working for Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api-v2, documentation, authentication

I have followed [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and used **explicit OAuth 2.0 flow** for `access_token` generation.

And I have gone through all 4 steps defined under explicit OAuth 2.0 flow with `scope=no_expiry`. Then I got the `access_token`.

When I am using `applicationKey` and `access_token` for fetch data through Stack Exchange API, I am getting following error :

```json
{
     "error_id": 403,
     "error_message": "`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token notfound.",
     "error_name": "access_denied"
}
```

I initially thought that there is something wrong with `applicationKey`.
Then I found that using same `applicationKey` (used for `access_token` generation) in request are working fine for other API Methods where `access_token` is not required.

Answer (score 2):

In my particular case, I somehow managed to append `%` character to the end of the `access_token`. There should be no `%` character at the end of the `access_token`.